# Filter data in Google Analytics by the Data Source property

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I had sent data to google analytics using the measurement protocol. To distinuish the data from the original web traffic, I had used the "Data Source" (DS) field (See https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters).

However I could not find a way how to filter this data on Google Analytics. Have anyone has idea how to seperate the two data sources in Google Anaytics? I would like to have a view that doesn't include/ have only this data source?

Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

according to the [Dimensions & Metrics Explorer](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=platform_or_device&jump=ga_datasource) you can filter the Data Type using a segment!